# How to divide into categories of continuous variables column of dataset in Decision Tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

When I Have a numeric column like 123 to 189 how can I know that how many groups can I divide this numbers and which threshold is a best option ?

Can anyone explain this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nurlan,well you have given very little information.

So the values of your column range from 123 to 189?

It all depends on the domain and the problem's context.

Say, if I had a column called Marks, ranging from 0-100,
I would try to categorize it into 3 classes - Low,Medium,High.
Maybe also try 4 classes - Low,Average,Medium,High.

And then compare performance in each case.

Another good approach would be to divide them by quartiles.

Pandas has [cut and qcut](https://pbpython.com/pandas-qcut-cut.html) for this purpose.